# attaching unit test data to unit tests in visual studio

Tags: visual-studio, unit-testing, tfs

I heavily make use of unit tests for my developer needs (POCs, unit tests, etc). For one particular test method there was a line that went...

```
var file = @"D:\data\file.eml";
```

So I am referencing some file on my file system.

Now in a team when other people are trying to run my "personal" tests (POCs or whatever) they don't have a reference to that file in that path...hence the tests fails. How we'd have to normally make this work is to provide the test data, and allow the user to modify the test code so that it runs on his computer.

Any visual studio way to manage this particular problem?

Whats the benefit in this? Well, people can review the test data (email in my case) as well as the method I wrote for testing, and can raise defects in TFS (the source control system) relating to it if need be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose the most straight forward way is to simply add whatever to the project, and set the correct value for **Copy To Output Directory**. In other words, say your data is in a text file.

1. Add text file to your test project
2. Right-click to access properties window
3. Set *copy to output directory* field as Always or Copy if newer.

Now if you build the test project, the file gets copied to your output directly. This enables to write unit test code of the fashion:

```
var dataFile = File.OpenRead("data.txt");
```

Answer (score 3):

One way I often handle data files for unit test projects are to set the data files as [Resources](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t69a74ty(v=vs.100).aspx). (* Note that this link is for vs2010 but I have used this approach through vs2015RC).

In the project with the data file:  **Project -> Properties -> Resources** and choose to *add a resource file* if you the project doesn't already have one.  Select *Files* in the resource pane and click *Add Resource* or just drag and drop your data files onto the resource manager.  By default resources are marked internal, so to access the resources from another project you have several ways:

1. In the assembly with the data files, add the following to your AssemblyInfo.cs file and this will allow only specified assemblies to access the internal resources

```cs
[assembly: InternalsVisibleTo("NameSpace.Of.Other.Assembly.To.Access.Resources")]
```

2. Create a simple provider class to abstract away the entire Resource mechanism, such as:

```cs
public static class DataProvider
{
    public static string GetDataFile(int dataScenarioId)
    {
        return Properties.Resources.ResourceManager.GetString(
            string.Format("resource_file_name_{0}", id));
    }
}
```

3. Change the resource management to public (not an approach I have used)
   You can then access the data file (now a resource) from a unit test such as:

```cs
[TestCase(1)]
public void X_Does_Y(int id)
{
    //Arrange
    var dataAsAString = Assembly_With_DataFile.DataProvider.GetScenario(id);

    //Act    
    var result = classUnderTest.X(dataAsAString);

    //Assert
    Assert.NotNull(result);
}
```

Note that using data files as resources, the [ResourceManager](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.resources.resourcemanager%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) handles the file I/O and returns strings of the file contents.

Update:  The test method in the example above is from an NUnit project and is not meant to imply process, but a mechanism by which a data file can be accessed from another project.

Comment: I would not embed my data files in every project, that also puts the test data in your actual project output and makes the assemblies larger than they should be. Making them resources in your TestProject makes sense to me :).

Answer (score 0):

What you'd normally do is add the file to your project and check it into TFS. Then make sure the item's settings are:

- Build action: Content
- Copy to output: If newer

Then put an attribute on your Test method or Test class:

```
[DeploymentItem("file.eml")]
```

You can optionally specify an output dircetory:

```
[DeploymentItem("file.eml", "Directory to place the item")]
```

If you put the files in subdirectories of your test project, then adjust the attribute accordingly:

```
[DeploymentItem(@"testdata\file.eml")]
```

The file will be copied to the working directory of your test project and that makes it easy to access from your test code. Either load the file directly, or pass the path to any method that needs it.

If you tests expect the files in a specific location you can use a simple `System.IO.File.Copy()` or `System.IO.File.Move()` to put the item in the place you need it to be.

The [process is explained here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182475.aspx) on MSDN.